# V 1.2.3 tutorial. Failure. Am I looking in right place?

Tags: apache-storm, stormcrawler

I am trying to follow the v 1.2.3 tutorial for apache storm.

Trying to get the ExclamationTopology  example from storm starter running.

I installed storm on my macbook using brew.
Which meant I ended up with apache storm v 1.2.3 
(And that would suit me fine cos I'm trying to get to a situation where I understand stormcrawler which seems to use 1.2.3 anyway.)

So, I spent a long time trying to see if I could view the output from the example and finally think I found the output in:

> /usr/local/Cellar/storm/1.2.3/libexec/logs/worders-artifacts

First question.. is that the right place to find the output?

Second Question:
the log file there is just full of messages as follows:

> 0.003s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:artifacts/gc.log instead. Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps' Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>   Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I had tried to get this whole lot running with jdk 1.8 as 1.7 was giving errors... so would that explain why this error is occurring ?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory layout for the brew install of Storm looks to be a little different than a standard Storm zip install. You are probably looking in the right place, yes.

The error message you're seeing is because you're running with some JDK version greater than 9. You can either use an older JDK (e.g. 8), or upgrade Storm to 2.0.0. Finally you can also work around the issue by editing/adding the `worker.childopts` option in your `storm.yaml`, which is somewhere in your storm install directory. Something like:

```
worker.childopts: "-Xmx%HEAP-MEM%m -Xlog:gc*:artifacts/gc.log:time,uptime:filecount=10,filesize=1M -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=artifacts/heapdump"
```

should work (this is the default in Storm 2.0.0).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. 
I actually removed the brew installation and just put the 1.2.3 storm bin on my path and got things running that way. I'm using java 8 with it and I'm seeing ok output in the logs now..